# Error: InvalidPipeArgument: 'function () { return fn.apply(this, arguments); }' for pipe 'AsyncPipe' Angular 7 Unit testing

Tags: angular, typescript, unit-testing, karma-jasmine

I'm writing unit test cases in Angular 7 in this process got stuck to create unit
test for a service variable 'isLoading'.

here is my app component html file:

```
<router-outlet></router-outlet>


<div *ngIf="guestUserService.isLoading | async"  class="loaderdiv">
  <mat-spinner class="loader"></mat-spinner>
</div>
```

The service file:

```
export class GuestUserService {

  public isLoading: any = new BehaviorSubject(false);

}
```

The unit test case:

```
 fdescribe('AppComponent', () => {
         let guestUserService: any;
         let guestUserServiceSpy: any;

          beforeEach(async(() => {
            guestUserService = jasmine.createSpyObj('GuestUserService', ['isLoading']);
            TestBed.configureTestingModule({
              providers: [
                { provide: GuestUserService, useValue: guestUserService }]
            }).compileComponents();
}));

 it('should render loader if isLoading true', () => {
    guestUserServiceSpy = guestUserService.isLoading.and.returnValue(true);
    fixture.detectChanges();
    const compiled = fixture.debugElement.nativeElement;
    expect(guestUserService).toBeDefined();
    expect(guestUserServiceSpy).toBeDefined();
    expect(guestUserService.isLoading).toBeTruthy();
    expect(fixture.debugElement.query(By.css('.loader'))).toBeDefined();
    expect(compiled.querySelector('mat-spinner')).toBeTruthy();
  });
```

Getting error:

> Error: InvalidPipeArgument: 'function () { return fn.apply(this,
>   arguments); }' for pipe 'AsyncPipe'

Is there any proper way to create unit test case for this type of scenarios.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There are several problems.

First, you're shooting yourself in the foot by using the type `any`. By doing this, the compiler let's you do things that don't make sense. And you also make the code harder to read for yourself. The `isLoading` property is supposed to be an `Observable<boolean>`, since that's what the template expects. So use that correct type instead of `any`.

Second, this line:

```
jasmine.createSpyObj('GuestUserService', ['isLoading'])
```

creates an object with a **function** named `isLoading`. But your actual service has a `property of type`Observable`` named `isLoading`, and that's what your template expects, hence the error: tha async pipe needs an observable as input, but you're passing it `isLoading`, which is a function in your test, and not an observable (see how using the right type helps reasoning about the errors you get?).

And BTW, this function returns a boolean true, instead of an `Observable<boolean>`

You could define a simple object instead of using jasmine to create your fake service:

```
const fakeService = {
    isLoading: of(true)
}
```

Or you could use jasmine but use its `spyOnProperty` function.

Or you could use `BehaviorSubject<boolean>` as the type of isLoading and thus use the real service implementation and simply make the subject emit true.

Comment: thanks, id d the same, returned function instead of property

Answer (score 4):

Just some extra information on creating Jasmine spy objects to fake services with get properties.

To create a spy object with get properties, the methods and properties need to be passed into the constructor separately:

```
createSpyObj('ExampleService’, { methods }, { get properties });
```

**Example**

The following 'Example' service has two methods and two get properties:

```
export class ExampleService {
  // properties
  public get exampleProperty1(): Observable<boolean> {
    // implementation...
  }
  public get exampleProperty2(): Observable<Number> {
    // implementation...
  }

  // methods
  public exampleMethod1(): void {
    // implementation...
  }
  public exampleMethod2(): void {
    // implementation...
  }
}
```

Create a Jasmine spy object for the example service like this:

```
fakeExampleService = jasmine.createSpyObj<ExampleService>(
  'FakeExampleService',
  {
    // pass in the methods here...
    exampleMethod1: undefined,
    exampleMethod2: undefined
  },
  {
    // pass in the properties here...
    exampleProperty1: of(false),
    exampleProperty2: of(1),
  }
);
```